# Spring mvc : How to pass the form data from jsp to controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Suppose I have this form in jsp

```
<form action="save" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="name" value="${person.name}">
 <input type="text" name="age" value="${person.age}">
 <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

And the Person class

```
public class Person {
 private String name;
 private String age;
 //getters and setters
}
```

Controller class

```
public class Controller {
 @RequestMapping(value="/save")
 public ModelAndView save(Person person){
  //save person
 }
}
```

Is that possible?Or I need to add some codes to make this work?I'm using spring mvc 4.0.3.
Thanks in advance. :)

EDIT : I tried @ModelAttribute but I got error 400. Tried using @RequestBody but error 415. Is it possible without using annotation?

EDIT : Controller implementation

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView list(){
        List<PersonDto> personDtos = personService.getAllPersons();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("persons",personDtos);
        model.addObject("roles",personService.getRoles());
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="view/{personId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView view(@PathVariable String personId){
        PersonDto personDto = new PersonDto();
        if (personId != null){
            personDto = personService.getPersonById(Integer.parseInt(personId));
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("person");
            model.addObject("person",personDto);
            return model;
        }
        else{
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/?message=Please select one person");
        }
    }   


    @RequestMapping(value="/add")
    public ModelAndView add(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("person");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/update", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView update(@RequestParam(value="personId",required=false) int[] personId){
        PersonDto personDto = new PersonDto();
        if (personId != null && personId.length == 1){
            personDto = personService.getPersonById(personId[0]);
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("person");
            model.addObject("person",personDto);
            return model;
        }
        else{
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/?message=Please select one person");
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView delete(@RequestParam(value="personId",required=false) int[] personId){
        if(personId != null){   
            for(int id : personId){
                personService.deletePerson(id);
            }
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/?message=Person/s deleted");
        }else{
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/?message=Please select person/s to delete");
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView search(@RequestParam(value="firstName",required=false) String firstName,
        @RequestParam(value="middleName",required=false) String middleName,
        @RequestParam(value="lastName",required=false) String lastName,
        @RequestParam(value="roles",required=false) String roles){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        List<PersonDto> personDtos = null;
        if (lastName.isEmpty() && firstName.isEmpty() && middleName.isEmpty() && roles.isEmpty()){
            personDtos = personService.getAllPersons();
        }
        else{
            personDtos = personService.searchPerson(lastName,firstName,
            middleName,roles);
        }
        model.addObject("persons",personDtos);
        model.addObject("roles",personService.getRoles());
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/test",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView test(PersonDto personDto){
        System.out.println(personDto);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/?message="+"Person saved");
    }
}
```

I have no problem calling other method but test.

Comment: first of all your should add `method=RequestMethod.POST` to your `@RequestMapping(value="/save")`. Like this: `@RequestMapping(value="/save, method=RequestMethod.POST")`

Answer (score 1):

Your Controller method and class should be like this

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

 @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST")
 public ModelAndView save(Person person){
  //save person

 return new ModelAndView("your url where you want to redirect after saing person");
 }
}
```

Comment: that's it? If I use person.getName(), will I get the name in the jsp?

Comment: yes only when you have same name of input field in form as filed name in person class

Comment: person.getName() only works when you fill your person object

Comment: Yes but if I submit the form, the person object must have value right? I already tried but I'm still getting a bad request.

Comment: yes when you submit the form person object have value and you can get by person.getName(), and can you please show the complete error?

Comment: Im not getting an erro in the console. Only in the browser. This is the error HTTP ERROR 400

Problem accessing /test. Reason:

    Bad Request

Powered by Jetty://

Comment: this error has nothing to do with this form submit code, i think you have error in your spring configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109528/discussion-between-daniel-bristol-and-ahmad).

Comment: if you can show your complete code, than i'll try to help you to get rid from this error.